# Drawing a 3D diagram with individual traces

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, 3d

I am looking for a way to transfer the image on the bottom right into an image with a 3D effect (similar to the image on the top left: please excuse my poor drawing skills).

[image]

At the moment I'm still looking for approaches how to best solve this task. I am grateful for any helpful tips. At the moment I think of Tikz and rotate....

Kind regards

Parsec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that one approach here could be the `3d` library from `tikz`. Specially the options `canvas is ...` which allows you to draw the desired functions in vertical planes as you show in your sketch.

This is a brief example with random functions, because I don't know your Fourier-like functions.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} % sometimes tikz and babel don't get along...

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.5cm,0.5cm)},z={(1cm,0cm)}]
% dimensions
\def\a{2}
\def\b{4}
\def\c{6}
% axes
\draw[-latex] (-4.5,0,0) -- (4.5,0,0) node [above] {$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0)  -- (0,4,0) node [above] {$A$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0)  -- (0,0,8) node [right] {$z$};
% auxiliary lines
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  \foreach\i in {\a,\b,\c}
    \draw[blue,dashed] (-4,\i) -- (4,\i);
  \foreach\i in {-1,1}
    \fill[x=\i cm] (1,0) --++ (0.5,0.5) --++ (1.5,0) --++ (0,-0.5) -- cycle ;
  \draw[blue,->] (-3.5 ,0) --++ (0,\a) node [midway,above]   {$a$};
  \draw[blue,->] (-3.75,0) --++ (0,\b) node [pos=0.75,above] {$b$};
  \draw[blue,->] (-4   ,0) --++ (0,\c) node [pos=0.85,above] {$c$};
\end{scope}
% curves
\draw[red,thick,canvas is xy plane at z=\a] plot[domain=-2:2,samples=101] (\x,\x*\x);
\draw[red,thick,canvas is xy plane at z=\b] plot[domain=-2:2,samples=101] (\x,{2*sin(150*\x)+2});
\draw[red,thick,canvas is xy plane at z=\c] plot[domain=-2:2,samples=101] (\x,0.5*\x*\x*\x*\x-\x*\x+0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent....my compliments.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastiano!!!

Comment: Wow!  That is really cool.  Thanks for letting me know about this capability.

Comment: Great implementation, as always!